# flutter makers pagination on google map

Tags: flutter, pagination, google-maps-markers

flutter mobile app. when the user opens the map his current location is detected and the initial camera position became his location. what I want

1. load makers that are near to the current location of the user.
2. if a user will scroll in any direction I want to add makers if are any in that area

it is like pagination on listview but I want to achieve this on the map through makers.
something that Redfin is doing.

NB: I'm using firebase to retrieve makers currently all makers are loaded at once on a map created. I think this is not a good way of doing this.

Please I need help  I have been trying for weeks now